# What instrument is this?

Tags: instruments

The song is [Green Back Boogie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Slgj96aXgQk), by Ima Robot, and I would like to know what instrument is that one that starts together with the vocal. It looks like a synth, or a distorted guitar. Wich one is that though? It seems too constant to be a guitar in my opinion, would that be a distorted pad or so?

Thank's for any help!

Comment: looks like an electric guitar with effects added on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's neither. The very beginning has vocals panned center, a low distorted sound in the left channel, and a low non-distorted but very compressed sound in the right channel (plus a shaker panned slightly right). Those are two different instruments playing the same part. Part of the giveaway is after the first half of the first verse (ending with "...in this life") staccato chords begin panned right, which are almost certainly an organ, most likely a Hammond B3.

That validates the idea that at the very beginning, the left channel sound really sounds like a B3 with a lot of distortion on it, like Deep Purple used to have (think of the intro to *Smoke On The Water* which is played on distorted B3).

Then the other instrument in the right channel is probably a bass guitar that is very compressed or possibly using a bass synth sound. It's possible that it is another keyboard track or a double of the B3 part, but the band did have a bass player during the recording of that album and it's unlikely there would be no bass on that song.

Comment: Thanks a lot, good analysis. Now I understand where center noise, almost percussive, is coming from, it's because it's an organ.

Comment: Feel free to upvote my answer if you like it.

Comment: I've been trying to reproduce it for practical purposes with a B3 plugin in Logic Pro, but I couldn't make the Rotor Sound well defined and in time as they did. Also the other sound, which I don't yet if it's part of the B3 or not, the "vrum vrum vrum" repeating sound in the center I also couldn't reproduce. Any tips on achieving those?